# Bootstrap 3 NavBar Move Link Underline Up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I built a standard fixed top navbar with a line height of 150 pixels for the desktop view of the site. Additionally I styled the links to have a red underline on hover but the underline is down at the bottom of the navbar rather than under the text.

I get that this is because of the line height but I'm wondering how to move it back up to just below the words.

Link to fiddle: [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/202fc5tp/)

Here is the CSS:

```
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 0;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li >   a:focus { border-bottom:3px solid #9e1e22; }
```

The HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Brand</a></div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Assessments</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Improvements</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Incident Response</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

Comment: Why are you using line height for this.  Would it be better to use padding to accomplish what you are looking for here?  That, or another property might be more appropriate to the effect you are after, and solve this underline problem as well.

Comment: @kylebellamy Is there any chance you could also upload a screenshot as i dont think your fiddle is working

Comment: I'm up for any solution to make this work better. How would I go about that?

Comment: It works, you just have to stretch the hell out of the page. I'll take the breakpoints out.

Comment: New Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/202fc5tp/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean? Keep the NAV at 150 but the hover directly under the link.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #9e1e22;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default {
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 45px;
  }
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #9e1e22;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a>

        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Assessments</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Improvements</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Incident Response</a>

        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong! Combining the line height with the link rather than using it on the box itself. Have to check that when I get back to my desk but I think you did it.

Comment: Should be it, then you can adjust your media queries to whatever you need,

Answer (score 0):

I know its not exactly what you after but rather than underlining the menu option, have you not thought of just changing the color of the menu option instead when hovered over.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
{
     color: #9e1e22;
}
```